# Scala js `@JSGlobal` object reference error

Tags: scala, scala.js

I had this small snippet of code: -

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSGlobal

object Main2 extends App {

  val js: Option[JS1] = for {
    jsTest <- JSTest.js1.toOption
  } yield jsTest

  println(js)

}

@js.native
@JSGlobal
object JSTest extends js.Object {
  def js1: js.UndefOr[JS1] = js.native
}


@js.native
trait JS1 extends js.Object {

  def js1: js.UndefOr[JS2] = js.native
}

@js.native
trait JS2 extends js.Object {
  def js2: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
}
```

When I try to run this I am getting this error: -

```
    const value = JSTest.js1;
                  ^

ReferenceError: JSTest is not defined
    at $c_LMain2$.delayedEndpoint$Main2$1__V (D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\file:\D:\experiment\src\main\scala\Main2.scala:8:15)
    at $c_LMain2$delayedInit$body.apply__O (D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\file:\D:\experiment\src\main\scala\Main2.scala:5:14)
    at $f_s_App__main__AT__V (D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\https:\raw.githubusercontent.com\scala\scala\v2.13.2\src\library\scala\Function0.scala:39:7)
    at $s_LMain2__main__AT__V (D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\file:\D:\experiment\src\main\scala\Main2.scala:5:8)
    at D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\experiment-fastopt.js:9360:1
    at D:\experiment\target\scala-2.13\experiment-fastopt.js:9361:4
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:132:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:315:38)
    at [stdin]:8:25
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:132:18)
[error] org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$NonZeroExitException: exited with code 1
[error]         at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$$anon$1.run(ExternalJSRun.scala:186)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / run for the full output
[error] (Compile / run) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSRun$NonZeroExitException: exited with code 1
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 20-Aug-2020, 5:47:54 pm
```

According to scala-js doc: - https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/global-scope.html

It should run but throwing this error can anybody let me know what the issue here?

**build.sbt**

```
name := "experiment"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
```

configuration:-

**Scala** -> 2.13.3, **SBT** -> 1.3.13, **JVM** -> Java 14, **scala-js** -> 1.1.1

Comment: Welcome @Divyanshu! You declare `JSTest` as a native JS global variable, but nothing in your question suggests that there is some JS code that actually defines that variable. What code is responsible for defining that variable?

Comment: I had simply created an sbt project with plugin dependency to enable scala-js as defined in this doc: - https://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial/basic/, having the build.sbt content as defined above and then created a file in src/main/scala/Main.scala and then pasted the code here, when I try to run it I got this error.

Comment: Right but then, I do not understand what you're expecting to happen. You're reading a variable `JSTest` that nobody defines. What else are you expecting if not a `ReferenceError`? In other words, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: JSTest is not a variable but a scala object and also I am trying to achieve something like this **@js.native @JSGlobal object Bar extends js.Object**

here from the doc: - https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/global-scope.html

Comment: According to scala object we can call a method inside scala object directly without needing to create an object https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

Comment: If you mark the object with `@js.native`, it's not a Scala object. It's a declaration for a JS object that needs to be defined by some JavaScript code somewhere. If you want to define Scala object, you should omit both `@js.native` and `@JSGlobal`, and you should provide an implementation for the methods instead of `= js.native`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220144/discussion-between-divyanshu-and-sjrd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked because of porting issue from scala 0.6.33 to scala 1.1.1 and The solution for this is answered on this: -

[scala-js "@JSGlobalScope" error when migrating to scala-js 1.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507979/scala-js-jsglobalscope-error-when-migrating-to-scala-js-1-1-1)