# scala-js "@JSGlobalScope" error when migrating to scala-js 1.1.1

Tags: scala, scala.js

I had a fallowing snippet of code in scala-js(0.6.33)

```
object Main2 extends App {

  val js = for {
    jsTest <- JSTest.js1.toOption
  } yield jsTest

  println(JSTest.js1)
}

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSGlobalScope

@js.native
@JSGlobalScope
object JSTest extends js.Object {
  def js1: js.UndefOr[JS2] = js.native
}
@js.native
trait JS1 extends js.Object {

  def js1: js.UndefOr[JS2] = js.native
}
@js.native
trait JS2 extends js.Object {
  def js2: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
}
```

And I was migrating the project to use scala-js(1.1.1)

when I compile the same code in scala-js(1.1.1), I am getting this error: -

```
const value = js1;
              ^

ReferenceError: js1 is not defined
```

Can anyone help me achieve the same functionality with scala-js(1.1.1)?

configuration: -

**scala** -> 2.13.3, **sbt** -> 1.3.13, **jvm** -> 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the release notes of Scala.js 1.0.0](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2020/02/25/announcing-scalajs-1.0.0/#accessing-a-member-that-is-not-declared-causes-a-referenceerror-to-be-thrown) explain, trying to even read a member of an `@JSGlobalScope` object that does not actually exist in the global scope will throw a `ReferenceError`, whereas Scala.js 0.6.x would give `undefined`.

The same section of the release notes explains that, if the purpose is to check whether it is defined, it is now necessary to use an explicit test with `js.typeOf`. In your specific example:

```scala
object Main2 extends App {
  val js = for {
    jsTest <- JSTest.js1.toOption
  } yield jsTest

  println(JSTest.js1)
}
```

That would mean that you can't unconditionally access `JSTest.js1` like that anymore. You first have to make sure it exists using a `js.typeOf` test:

```scala
object Main2 extends App {
  val safeJS1 =
    if (js.typeOf(JSTest.js1) == "undefined") None
    else JSTest.js1.toOption

  val js = for {
    jsTest <- safeJS1
  } yield jsTest

  println(safeJS1)
}
```